# Play! framework calling the render() action from controller

Tags: templates, playframework

I've been customising a template generated by the CRUD module and now need to override the save method to save the custom data from the template. I can save all the data, but when I call the render action:

```
render("Users/show.html", user);
```

I get a nullPointerException for templates object:

[image]

I'm definitely passing the correct user object through because when I run this:

```
System.out.println(user.toString());
//render("Users/show.html", user);
```

It writes my user to the console.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[Controller](http://www.pastebucket.com/AppView/895)
[View](http://pastebucket.com/896)

Play! 1.2.3

Comment: Are you passing the user object in a method with @After annotation? Passing the user object in renderArgs in another method could also overide the value passed to the template.

Comment: can u share your controller code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your controller is rendering

```
render("Users/show.html", user);
```

but the name of the element in your template is *object*. It should be *user*.

**UPDATE ON COMMENT**

The original templates on CRUd use "object" as an abstraction to the entity under CRUD. If you check the source code of the controller, it says:

```
//ignoring case when template is not found, alternative also uses object
render(type, object);
```

This means that there are two options:

1. You modified the template breaking this compatibility. It doesn't seem to be the case in your scenario, although we can't see the full code (so it may still be an option)
2. You modified the controller, changing the objects you send to the template. It seems to be your scenario. So either you fix the template to use *user* or you rename *user* to *object*.

Comment: I'm overriding the template generated by the CRUD module, I think it uses object as a generic name. I tried to change it to user as you suggested, it made no effect to the error I'm getting.

Comment: Thanks! the second option has resolved the issue, but has seemed to cause another. it no longer seems to be saving the duties that i'm trying to add, before all the information in the form would be saved and when i tried to call the render function the template would fall over. Now it does not seem to be saving all the data, and is rendering the page, but I think I should probably ask this in a new question. thank you.